# Activated filter in datagrid not refreshed if data has changed

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

I have an issue with refiltering if data has changed.

Please see this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-light-theme-v11-oosuvk

The column is prefiltered with 'AA'. If you select a row, change the value to 'BB', the row stays in the datagrid, therefore the filter has not been "refreshed".

How can I achieve that the datagrid detects changes and refilters it? The value of the column is being refreshed, so why is it not being refiltered?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to force update the `clrFilterValue`. I managed to refresh the filter by double-binding `clrFilterValue`, and updating it in the component via a temporary variable :

In the .html :

```
<clr-dg-column [clrDgField]="'name' [(clrFilterValue)]="filterValue">Name</clr-dg-column>
[...]
<input #input value="{{selectedItem.name}}">
<button (click)="onSave(input.value)">Save</button>
```

In the .ts :

```
public filterValue = 'AA';
onSave(value) {
    this.selectedItem.name = value;
    let tmp = this.filterValue;
    this.filterValue = this.filterValue + ' ';
    setTimeout(
      () => {
          this.filterValue = tmp;
      }, 0
    )
  }
}
```

However, using `setTimeout()` is not what I prefer... Hope this helped.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this seems like a very hacky workaround. I'm sure I am not the only one with this use case and am sure there is an implementation from clarity to do this...? :)

Comment: Yes I am aware that this solution is a bit tricky... I looked in clarity Docs but I did not find any input that you can use to force the filtering, that's why I chose to use data-binding update to update the filter. I hope you will find the good way of doing this :)

Answer (score 0):

The quickest non-hacky way to do this is to call the public `dataChanged()` method on the datagrid to update the displayed items due to a change in the data that the datagrid isn't aware of: https://stackblitz.com/edit/datagrid-edit-refresh?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

**I would highly recommend, however**, that you work with immutable objects when displaying them in a Datagrid. The reason is that for obvious performance concerns, the datagrid cannot perform deep object comparison on every item during every change detection cycle. It **will** check whether items have been added or removed from the overall list of items, but will not check whether their properties have changed. This is the exact same behavior as `*ngFor`, and is considered standard for almost all structural directives.
In your case, this would mean that the editing logic changes from

```
selectedItem.name = name
```

to:

```
new Item = {...selectedItem, name};
items.splice(selectedItemIndex, 1, newItem);
```

If you were to do this, you wouldn't need to force a datagrid update manually.